# Using Exclude on inferred type results in 'never' in typescript

Tags: typescript

My goal is to be able to preconfigure some props of a component in a function, and have that function return a component that won't require the preconfigurated props. Here is a code illustrating that: ([here is the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQUQB7ZgAmaRAwnALYAOAPAAopzUDOAfABQU0BciH1Jqz6NmLAJSIAvG0QYwAT0kBvAFCJkCFlET5CJYt2rT+gsSKETpstRo3ooIFEiMDL49YgC+nvWmL+5FTUAHRYUCgsJrQASmgsIAA2OmgEgVH0GCiwGIkMlmyc4ZF8cQnJkjKItnYQWjqMaHVgwDAA5k5YpEYmbua6eBCJICT5YgA0iGVJUGyVNp52iA5OLsEcyiFbZqyTW2FQESxeHks+SyvOiI3NrR0oXUE0nufLaI5XfgGGwao+qqBILAEIgen1hNVENhtHxtCgYGA2pNtApEmhYREEW1vCpPJckDsWH9VM1tNd0Ld2j0pMh0F0viQntQuMFxAcjhsofEoHwAORwADWvJxqhuCDurmUiBRaL50KgwpOQA)):

```js
function createExtendedComp<Props>(Comp: (props: Props) => any) {
  const ExtendendComp = (props: Props) => {
    return Comp(props)
  }
  ExtendendComp.attrs = <Result extends Partial<Props>>(attrs: Result) => {
    const PreconfiguratedComp = (props: Exclude<Props, Result>) => {
      return Comp({...props, ...attrs})
    }
    return PreconfiguratedComp
  }
  return ExtendendComp
}

function Comp (props: { test: string, style: string }) {
  return props
}
const PreconfigComp = createExtendedComp(Comp).attrs({ test: 'ok' })
PreconfigComp({ style: 'test' }) // <- Argument of type '{ style: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

There seem to be a problem with the type inferred for Result. Typescript thinks that it should be `never`, while I would expect it to be `{ style: string }`

How can I remove from `Props` the parts that are already handled in `Result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to use `Exclude` here, but `Omit`.

```
    const PreconfiguratedComp = (props: Omit<Props, keyof Result>) => {
```

Something along the lines of:

```
function createExtendedComp<Props>(Comp: (val: Props) => any) {
  const ExtendendComp = (props: Props) => {
    return Comp(props)
  }

  ExtendendComp.attrs = <Result extends Partial<Props>>(attrs: Result) => {
    const PreconfiguratedComp = (props: Omit<Props, keyof Result>) => {
      return Comp({...props, ...attrs} as Props)
    }

    return PreconfiguratedComp
  }

  return ExtendendComp
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. You're the goat!